# Struggling with application of inheritance concepts in simpleish java program

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to dynamically declare a variable of the type of its superclass to be the subclasses but I am not sure how.

The program is a card game with a user and NPCs:

```
public class Player {
     private int playerNumber;

     public Player(int playerNumber) {
          this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
       }
}

public class User extends Player {
    public User(int playerNumber) {
        super(playerNumber);
    }
    public void clickInteraction() {...}
}

public class NPC extends Player {

    private Hand hand;
    private int playerNumber;
    private int score ;
    private Actor scoreActor;

    IFilterBehaviour filterBehaviour;
    ISelectBehaviour selectBehaviour;

    public NPC(int playerNumber, IFilterBehaviour filterBehaviour, ISelectBehaviour selectBehaviour){
        super(playerNumber);
        this.filterBehaviour = filterBehaviour;
        this.selectBehaviour = selectBehaviour;
        this.hand = null;
        this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
    }

    //strategy pattern filter
    //@Override
    public ArrayList<Card> filter(Hand hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps) {...}
        
    //strategy pattern select
    //@Override
    public Card select(ArrayList<Card> hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps) {...}
  }
```

I want to keep track of who is playing under the type player because the same rules apply to NPCs and users, so I am trying to use something like this:

```
Player nextPlayer = playersArray(random.nextInt(nbPlayers))
```

I want to be able to use the methods of either `NPC` or `User` but obviously I can't use nextPlayer.filter when filter is an NPC method. Can I do something like this?

```
if (playersArray(random.nextInt(nbPlayers)) instance of npc) {
        nextPlayer be treated as npc
} 
else { nextPlayer be treated as user }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call the same method on both types of players, declare `Player` as an `interface` and any methods you want sub-classes to implement... If you want each type of player to have a `playerNumber`/`playerId`, have another abstract class `PlayerId` with the field you want.

Looks to me like you have `NPC` declaring its own `playerNumber` (which is already declared in the parent class) `Player`. This is redundant and can be removed.

Unless you **need** to "down cast" a `Player` to `NPC`/`User` for a specific method call to be made, you'd typically want to avoid this.

If you can keep methods defined at `Player` level that apply to all players, you'll have an easier time implementing and calling the required methods.

e.g.

```java
class PlayerDefinitions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User(0);
        NPC npcPlayer = new NPC(1, filterBehaviour, selectBehavior);
        
        List<Card> nullList_or_emptyList = user.filter(...);
        Card nullCard = user.select(...);
        
        List<Card> aListOfCards = npcPlayer.filter(...);
        Card aCard = npcPlayer.select(...);
    }
}



interface Player {
    // methods that apply to all players go here

    // You can provide a no-op implementation for User if not required by User
    ArrayList<Card> filter(Hand hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps);
    Card select(ArrayList<Card> hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps)
}

abstract class PlayerId {
    private int playerId;

    public PlayerId(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }
}

class User extends PlayerId implements Player {

    public User(int playerNumber) {
        super(playerNumber);
    }

    public void clickInteraction() {
        // some code
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Card> filter(Hand hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Card select(ArrayList<Card> hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps) {
        return null;
    }
}

class NPC extends PlayerId implements Player {

    private Hand hand;
    private int score;
    private Actor scoreActor;

    IFilterBehaviour filterBehaviour;
    ISelectBehaviour selectBehaviour;

    public NPC(int playerNumber, IFilterBehaviour filterBehaviour, ISelectBehaviour selectBehaviour) {
        super(playerNumber);
        this.filterBehaviour = filterBehaviour;
        this.selectBehaviour = selectBehaviour;
        this.hand = null;
    }

    //strategy pattern filter
    @Override
    public ArrayList<Card> filter(Hand hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps) {...}

    //strategy pattern select
    @Override
    public Card select(ArrayList<Card> hand, Hand trick, Whist.Suit trumps) {...}
}
```

I'd also suggest you have a `Game` class that controls which player's turn it is rather than trying to get have all players keep track of who the active player is. This separation will keep things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using casting. Something like this

```
 Player nextPlayer = playersArray(random.nextInt(nbPlayers)) ;
 if(nextPlayer instanceof NPC) {
      NPC npc= (NPC) nextPlayer;
      .....[do something with npc]
  } 
  else {
       
      .....[Do something with nextPlayer] 
  }
```

Not so elegant maybe but it should work

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you know if I can do this but with redefining nextPlayer, like not using a new NPC type. Because the nextPlayer has to be used in alot of subsequent code that I wouldnt want to  put in both the if and else.

Comment: i don't understand what you need